# angularjs, load local json results in "SyntaxError: Unexpected token ' "

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I saw somewhere that this is because the content type of the json file isn't "application/json" but how can I get this to work on my local machine?

What I'm trying to do is to load two separate json files which contains the translations of the page. But it seems pretty much impossible, probably isn't.

```
var medicalApp = angular.module('medicalApp', ['ngRoute', 'ngResource', 'ngCookies']);

// configure our routes
medicalApp.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        ...
});

medicalApp.factory('getDE', function($resource, $http) {
    //return $resource('../translations/de.json');
    var defaults = $http.defaults.headers;
    defaults.get = defaults.get || {};
    defaults.get['Content-Type']='application/json';

    var values = $resource('../translations/de.json', {}, {
        query: {method:'GET',headers:{'ignored':'ignored'}}
    });

    console.log(JSON.stringify(values));

    return values;
});

medicalApp.factory('getFR', function($resource, $http) {
    //return $resource('../translations/fr.json');
    var defaults = $http.defaults.headers;
    defaults.get = defaults.get || {};
    defaults.get['Content-Type']='application/json';

    var values = $resource('../translations/fr.json', {}, {
        query: {method:'GET',headers:{'ignored':'ignored'}}
    });

    console.log(JSON.stringify(values));

    return values;
});

...

medicalApp.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $cookies, getFR, getDE) {
    var userLang = navigator.language || navigator.userLanguage;
    var lang = userLang.substring(0,2);
    if (lang == 'fr') {
        getFR.get(function(data){
            alert(JSON.stringify(data));
        });
    } else {
        getDE.get(function(data){
            alert(JSON.stringify(data));
        });
    }
});
```

Any ideas of how I can get this working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you have `'` instead of `"` somewhere in your json file. check it's validity [here](http://jsonlint.com/), or show us it's content